# Improve quality of tesseract text recognition

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I try to build an iOS app that can scan the vin number from a car. I'm having some problems with the accuracy of the scan.

I use opencv to find the contours/bounding boxes of the text and so far I have this result:

[image: ocr result]

As you can see I have great result with finding the boxes of the text and I'm cropping the image according to the green frame before sending it to tesseract.

Tesseract however does not give a good result. Sometimes I get the correct text and sometimes it give me something else.

I use tesseract 3.03 from the following Pod: https://github.com/kevincon/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/tree/tesseract3.03

I use the default english training dict and I setup Tesseract like:

```
tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng"];
[tesseract setVariableValue:@" 0123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
[tesseract setVariableValue:@"language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word" forKey:@"0"];
[tesseract setVariableValue:@"language_model_penalty_non_dict_word" forKey:@"0"];
[tesseract setVariableValue:@"load_system_dawg" forKey:@"0"];
[tesseract setVariableValue:@"load_freq_dawg" forKey:@"0"];
```

Any ideas on how I can improve the accuracy of this scan?

**UPDATE 1:**
My next step will be to create traindata. I will try an use this image:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63179/ocr/traindoc.jpg
I us the font helvetica neue regular since it looks quiet similar. I know that my text will only contain numbers and uppercase characters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate .traindata? I've made something similar for credit card number recognition. But it did not work out of box.

I used **jTessBoxEditor** and **SerakTesseractTrainer** to generate **.traindata** for specific fonts which are used for credit cards.

But anyway - result was not so good as I expected. Accuracy was pretty bad if I scan number with slightly different font.

Comment: My next step will be to create traindata. Were your results bad even with traindata?

Comment: It was perfect for printed text with same font on paper. But If font is slightly different - it starts making mistakes sometimes. Also it depends of image quality, it will not recognize barely visible text.

Comment: And most important, I did not achieve results I wanted (probably because of bad **.traindata** and missing fonts), so I dropped this idea and start using PayPal's card.io closed library